# Links in ReactNative TextView

Tags: react-native, hyperlink

I want to add an external link in ReactNative TextView. How can be done this ?

I just tried this, it is working, but I want to have all the links with the default color.

```
<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}
      onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://google.com')}>
  View more details
</Text>
```

Is there a library ReactNative library only for links generation?

Comment: So what you are looking for is only how to underline the text and changing the color to blue/purple?

Comment: i'm looking for a better way to implement this hyperlink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HI I would make a custom component as below.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {Text} from 'react-native'

export default ({url, text}) => {
  return <Text 
    style={{color: 'blue'}} 
    onPress={() => Linking.openUrl(url)}
  >{text}</Text>
}
```

Then you can use it as follows.

```
import Link from './link' // Where ever it is.
import * as React from 'react'

export default() => {
  return <Link url="http://google.com" text="View more details" />
}
```

This way you can have all your links blue, and in the future if you prefer yellow you can change one line and all links will change colour.
Good luck, if anything is unclear please let me know.